# How to store an output of "git pull", without deleted files, numbers and duplications, for listing new files in a text file?

Tags: git, sorting, fish, uniq

I use mostly Fish instead of Bash and Zsh. I want to output a whole `fast-forward`'s `git pull` since March until today, but only the modified and new files, without number of additions, deletions and modifications, without duplications, to list the new icons for a text file, so I will copy the missed new icons to another branch.

For example:

```
git pull > new_icons.txt
```

I want to use these commands, but I need the options to exclude the deleted files, the duplications and the numbers of additions, deletions and modifications

```
git pull > new_icons.txt 2 > &1
git pull |& tee new_icons.txt
git pull &> new_icons.txt
```

If you do not know what "number of additions, deletions and modifications" are, for example:

[image]

You can see `|`, numbers, `+` and `-`. I want to exclude them when I output in a text file.

And what are the duplications?

For example:

```
February 7
Fast-forward
   icon.svg | 3+++

February 24
Fast-forward
   icon.svg | 2--

March 7
Fast-forward
   icon.svg | 1++
```

I want to output only a **unique** `icon.svg`.

I am not sure if I can use the command `fmt -1 | sort -z | uniq -cd | xargs echo` for `git pull`, like:

```
git pull |& fmt -1 | sort -z | uniq -cd | xargs echo |& tee new_icons.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `git pull` is just `git diff --stat` between the commits before/after the pull.

e.g : run `git diff --stat d649d3e f0c56e2`, and you should see the same output as in your screenshot.

---

Spot the root commit you want (the state of your repo in March), and use `git diff`.

For your use case, `git diff` has other useful options :

- `--name-status` will show the names of impacted files, prefixed with `A,M or D` (resp: Added, Modified or Deleted)
- `--name-only` will display the filenames, without further information
- `--diff-filter=[(A|M|D)]` will allow you to display information only about files matching the filter

See the complete docs : [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)
(I simplified the description of `diff-filter` and `name-status`, the full doc can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) and [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---name-status))

The list you are looking for is :

```
git diff --no-renames --diff-filter=AM --name-only [basecommit] [branch]
```

Since you somehow want to "apply a patch" on some other branch, you may also need the list of deleted files (to delete them ...) :

```
git diff --no-renames --diff-filter=D --name-only [basecommit] [branch]
```

The following list is helpful to understand what happened between the two commits :

```
git diff --name-status [basecommit] [branch]
```

Comment: Does it outputs only the unique files (removing duplications)? If not, will I add `sort -z | uniq -d`?

Comment: Yes, a single file can only appear once in a diff

Comment: Just another final question. Does `git diff` sort alphabetically in case-sensitive form?

Comment: I think it will in practice, but I don't know if it is a hard guarantee of `git diff`. Just `sort` the result and you will be sure.